Preventing Auto-Clearing in onDraw() When Redrawing Graphs in Android
In Android, I am trying to create graphs, and I am rendering the graph by inheriting the View class and painting it in the onDraw () function using Canvas.
Now at times, the OS itself calls the onDraw() function during for example resizing etc., But during redraw, it will remove all the contents and starts drawing again.
Is it possible to tell the draw signal to not remove the existing content and not do anything?
